# How to get the children of a Logger (java.util.logger)

Tags: java, logging

I'm currently working with Java logging.
I've got a logger `cwh.A` and `cwh.B`. Is it possible to get these loggers via Java from the logger `cwh`, without knowing their names?

Comment: I'd like to make a window where you can select all Loggers in a JTree, to watch that specific logger. Could be usefull to debug a specific class.

Comment: I don't think there is a reference to "child" loggers in the cwh logger.

Comment: No, but somehow, somewhere, all loggers are cached, as "the appropriate logger is returned, or created"

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get all logger-names via the logmanager:

```
LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
        Enumeration<String> names = manager.getLoggerNames();
        while(names.hasMoreElements()){
            String name = names.nextElement();
            if(name.startsWith("cwh.")){
                //work with the name of the logger
            }
        }
```

With this workaround, the child-loggers can be found.

Comment: probably want a startswith `"chw."`.

Comment: Not really necessary, as I don't have a package that starts with cwh, but indeed. I'll edit it right away